# New off topic reason required for flags

Tags: feature-request, flagging

The off topic flags don't currently offer any option for when a question doesn't fit within the framework of Workplace. I site [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22332/does-linkedin-recruiter-help-consultancies-or-agencies-in-the-way-it-should-be) as an example; it's not relevant at all to Workplace and so when trying to flag I was looking for something along those lines, but there are only 3 specific reasons for flagging a question off topic currently.

We need an option along the lines of *This question is off topic because it doesn't appear to be about the workplace.* This would be similar to how SO has an option for flagging questions for not being about programming.

Comment: Those with close vote privileges do have an "other" option where they can enter a custom reason for voting to close, but it is true that those *flagging* to close only see the canned custom close reasons. This may definitely be worth consideration.